# AngularJS Scope of function in promise

Tags: angularjs

I'm having a problem understanding promises in AngularJS.

I have something like the following:

```
var loader = angular.module('loadIt', []);

loader.factory('loadService', function($http, $q) {
  return {
    getJs: function(path) {
      var deferred = $q.defer();

      $http.get(path).then(function(response) {
        deferred.resolve(response.data);
      });

      return deferred.promise;
    }
  }
});

var myMod = angular.module('myMod', ['loadIt']);

myMod.service('mymodService', function(loadService) {

  this.vals = {};
  this.readIt = function (pos) {
            this.vals[pos] = loadService.getJs('aaa.js');
  }

});
```

In the debugger, I see the line:

```
this.vals[pos] = loadService.getJs('aaa.js');
```

The correct value is being returned by the getJs() call.
But the scope is wrong.  this.vals isn't defined inside the readIt function.
How can I fix that?

**Edit**

I also tried the following:

```
  this.readIt = function (pos) {
     loadService.getJs('aaa.js').then(function(data) {
        this.vals[pos] = data;
    });
  }
```

Here I see that data contains the JSON object read from a file.

this refers to object Window and this.vals does not exist in the scope.

Comment: What do you see in the console ?

Comment: Not the console, but while debugging I can see data is a JSON object, but only data and this (Window) are in the local scope

Answer (score 2):

Since you've chosen to use a service (rather than a factory), you need to assign `this` to another variable (often `self` as below) if you wish to reference it from within the scope of another function. Otherwise, the fact that `this`'s context changes within the `then` callback function is problematic.

```
myMod.service('mymodService', function(loadService) {
  this.vals = {};
  var self = this;

  this.readIt = function (pos) {
    loadService.getJs('aaa.js').then(function(data){
      self.vals[pos] = data;
    });
  }
});
```

Using the above code, you could then set a scope variable like so:

```
myMod.controller('MyController', function($scope, mymodService, $timeout){
  mymodService.readIt(0);
  $scope.vals = mymodService.vals;
})
```

If you find that this approach is not working for you initially, compare [**this demo**](http://plnkr.co/edit/kLORoafHmlnwjUmY2jIU?p=preview) against your code and consider what you might need to refactor.

**Additional Note:**

If you don't like the `var self = this` syntax, consider using a factory instead of a service:

```
myMod.factory('mymodService', function(loadService) {
  var modservice = {
    vals: {}
  };

  modservice.readIt = function (pos) {
    loadService.getJs('aaa.js').then(function(data){
      modservice.vals[pos] = data;
    });
  }

  return modservice;
});
```

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/8FOqiDpJ7Vzd0TbzLUWL?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks.  I see both examples working, but mine still isn't.  So I'll need to work a bit more on it to see what's the problem.

Comment: I tried rewriting it as a factory, like you had suggested.  But I saw the same problem.  I've worked around it by calling loadService.getJs(path, this) and returning a reference to 'this' as an argument to the function in the then().  I must be doing something wrong somewhere.  I've given you a point for your help.

Comment: It's hard to say what the problem is. If your workaround works, then good! If you want a review of your code to help identify the problem, then it would be best for you to create a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=catalogue) which demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 potential issues here.

1) `loadService.getJs()` returns a promise.  So you're assigning a promise, rather than the actual value to `this.vals[pos]`.  Assuming you want the actual value assigned then you want

```
loadService.getJs().then(function(data) {
      this.vals[pos] = data;
  });
```

2) `this` refers to the calling context.  So within `readIt()` `this` will refer to whatever object called it- rather than the lexical scope it is defined in (`mymodService` in this case).  But you can use [`bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to fix that. `bind` lets us force what `this` will be bound to when a function executes. So, adding `bind()` to the end of your callback, your code now looks like:

```
this.vals = {};
this.readIt = function (pos) {
  loadService.getJs().then(function(data) {
      this.vals[pos] = data;
  }.bind(this));   
}
```

`this` can be tricky - if you want a bit more detail you might checkout [this blog by Dan Wahlin](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/working-with-the-javascript-this-keyword)

Here's a stripped down [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zJ4Fu/2/) with both changes that shows it all wired up within a views $scope.

Comment: Thanks. I see it working in fiddle, but for me, within the then(), vals isn't defined, only data and this (Window)

Comment: I think the theory behind the second part of your answer is incorrect. `this` does refer to the service (not the caller) and when you use `vals = {}` (without var or this.), it is set on the `window` object: http://jsfiddle.net/marcolepsy/aE744/

Comment: I think my problem may be that I don use "myApp.service" and "myApp.factory" in my original code?  I was trying to make this factory and service more portable and not dependent directly on the app.

Comment: No, I don't think that  is your problem at all. You can segment the modules however you want as long as you inject them into the main app.

Comment: @MarcKline Good point.  While this always refers to the calling context.  That's kind of the point of `this`.  But I forgot to put a `var` in front of vals (turning into a global)- I'm used to strict mode catching that.

Comment: @GeorgeHernando I updated the answer with a version that makes fewer changes to your code, so it'll hopefully be easier to port over to your code base.  See it solves your issue.

Comment: What you'd written previously lead me to believe you were saying you shouldn't use `this` in a service. Your edits cleared it up for me.

Comment: @MarcKline No worries, my wording wasn't very clear.  I tried rephrasing it so it's hopefully more helpful.  Thanks for catching the bug in my original code!

Comment: I converted my answer to a community wiki (ie no points) since now that you'd edited yours, there is a great amount of parity between the two. I'm leaving it up in case the variation of examples is helpful to the OP.